# creating android project in eclipse from folder content

Tags: android, eclipse

I guess this is an easy thing for eclipse experts - unfortunately, I am not that good yet to find the solution myself. I tried to use "Configure Build Path" but really don't know how.

I got an android demo project which is saved in two sub-folders. In folder structure is as follows:

```
main
-demo_main
--manifest
--gen
--res
--src
---a
----b
-----demo
------Class1.java
-extraPackage
--manifest
--gen
--res
--src
---a
----b
-----widget
------adapters
-------AdapterClass1.java
------WidgetClass1.java
```

the file Class1 from demo_main references and uses classes from extraPackage like this:

import a.b.R;
import a.b.widget.WidgetClass1;

How can I create a project in eclipse with these files so that the references match and that I can run the project using eclipse.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create a blank Android project first, then use the File -> Import option from the menu and import from filesystem, which basically copies the resources into the project you just created.

[image: This is the dialog of the File|Import option]

Comment: thanks that helped alot and put me in the right direction - also one needs to try "New Project" -> "Create Project from existing source". This will create the project and set all the references correctly